# ASP.NET MVC combined with Web API or..... Nancyfx?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, razor, model-view-controller

I've never used traditional ASP.NET MVC and started with Nancyfx. I'm considering making the switch to ASP.NET MVC + Web API but have some general questions.

I think I may have been spoiled with Nancyfx but I have some real problems and concerns with it which is why I'm not sure on it for my rewrite. The main problem is the load times. I understand it compiles the Razor views upon first load which extends the load times but there are bugs that cause it to not work (known issues). I've implemented a work-around but I've read that ASP.NET MVC can pre-compile to avoid this situation (Nancyfx cannot).

Doing some research with ASP.NET MVC + Web API it seems the Web API is for the restful endpoints while the ASP.NET MVC is for serving the pages. As you know, Nancyfx combines these two technologies into one which is what is really nice. Am I correct about this or is there a way around to make ASP.NET MVC serve the Razor pages plus serve the JSON/XML requests depending on the request type?

I do not really care to use ASP.NET core to be honest because my application integrates heavily into Active Directory, Microsoft Exchange and other Windows application that are not on other platforms. Someone wanting to deploy it on a Linux server is kind of pointless IMO for what I'm doing.

Comment: I'd recommend investigating .NET Core. I know you don't think it is the right fit, but it is the platform getting the most investment. If you are going to switch stacks, you may as well switch to the stack that is the 'newest'.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, ASP.NET MVC offers you two controller base classes: **Controller** and **ApiController**. You inherit from the **Controller** class if you want to create view-based controller actions and you inherit from **ApiController** if you want to create API actions. On the other hand, in ASP.NET Core, you can use the same controller infrastructure to deliver views as well as REST APIs. You can always combine .NET Framework and ASP.NET Core. However, .NET + ASP.NET Core solution works only on Windows about which you apparently have no problem.

Comment: I started today with the separate Controller and ApiController's and understand much better how it works. Sounds like ASP.NET core works more like Nancyfx did with combining controllers if that is what you are saying. I know everyone is recommending API Core, just don't know if it is the right choice unless I completely separate the calls (the front end calls a Windows Service which then runs all the remote powershell commands).